# <select> tag not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a program in which I show the value selected in the menu. I don't understand why the [<select> tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) doesn't work.

**Html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src='script.js'></script>
    </head>    
    <body>          
        <form>
            <Label for="country">Country</Label>
            <select name="country" id= "country">
                <option name="country" id="country">Country</option>
                <option name="USA" id="country">USA</option>
                <option>India</option>
                <option>China</option>
                <option>France</option>
                <option>England</option>
                <option>Ecuador</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"></input>
        </form>
        <p id="demo"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Script**

```
var country=$('#country :selected');
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = country;
```

Comment: use document.ready function if you using jquery

Comment: Wrap your code in Doc Ready - `$(function(){...});` and use `$('#country :selected').val()`

Answer (score 2):

Always use an ID attribute uniquely, you are using it 3 times, consider using classes for that.

This is how you want it:

```js
//Wait until the page is ready for manipulation
$(function(){
    //Whenever the value of #country changes, do:
    $("#country").on('change', function() {
        //Get the new value
        var country = $(this).val();

        //Put the new value into the #demo element
        $("#demo").html(country);
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <Label for="country">Country</Label>
        <select name="country" id="country">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select your country</option>
            <option value="USA">USA</option>
            <option value="india">India</option>
            <option value="china">China</option>
            <option value="france">France</option>    
            <option value="england">England</option>
            <option value="ecuador">Ecuador</option>
        </select>
        
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"></input>
    </form>

    <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script **must** be placed at **the end** of document or in **`$(document).ready(..)`** like below.

Please make sure to *subscribe* to [`.change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event, that every time the `selected value` is *changed* to place it where you want.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#country').change(function() { // every times is changed
    $('#demo').html($(this).val()); // add value in tag with id #demo
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#country').change(function() { // every times is changed
    $('#demo').html($(this).val()); // add value in tag with id #demo
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <Label for="country">Country</Label>
  <select name="country" id="country">
    <option>Country</option>
    <option>USA</option>
    <option>India</option>
    <option>China</option>
    <option>France</option>
    <option>England</option>
    <option>Ecuador</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: because the HTML code is still completely wrong, it's using 3 identical id attributes and name attributes within <option> instead of value attributes

Comment: @xorinzor thank you for noticing me, now is corrected